# Branching in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, dvcs

I have starting using Mercurial for my (our) versioning needs. I have now come to the point that I need to create a feature branch. However, now that I have started working on it -- and I try to push my changes, I keep getting a warning about new remote heads. That's stupid, I know that there will be new remote head(s) that's what a branch after all is?

How am I supposed to create branches and push them without this problem, without using force push as it is surely not the right way to go, right?

I thought about using separate repositories, but that feels just stupid especially for feature branches.

Any help welcome!

Comment: Essentially a duplicate (from a different angle) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948574/why-is-a-new-branch-flag-needed - you might find the answers there useful as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To date, the best guide out there is Steve Losh's "[A Guide to Branching in Mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/)".

Mercurial will always complain about creating new heads on the remote.  You must use either `--force` or `--new-branch` when creating a new head.

When using TortoiseHg, the same can be accomplished via the `Synchronize` view of the Workbench.  Click `Options` and then select the `Allow push of a new branch` or `Force push or pull` option, as needed.

[image: TortoiseHg v2.x]

The reason it behaves this is way is that the Mercurial developers wanted to make it a conscious decision to create a new head on the remote.  Their view is that typical workflows should merge changes prior to pushing.

Comment: What's the equivalent action on TortoiseHG for `--new-branch`, see, I don't use command line so often.

Comment: +1 for the reasoning. It's at least as instructive as the actual answer.

Comment: @rFactor: I updated my answer to include notes for TortoiseHg.

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial by Joel Spolsky helped me a bunch when I just started out with mercurial. It might be helpful for you as well:

http://hginit.com/