# Mercurial: how to push to default branch?

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial and am a bit of a newbie. I just committed a change to my repo successfully, then ran `hg pull` and `hg update` successfully - no merges and no conflicts showed up.

Then I tried to push to the remote repo, and got the dreaded: `abort: push creates new remote heads!`

`hg glog` shows the following:

```
@  changeset:   576:c4c58970f141
|  tag:         tip
|  user:        me
|  parent:      566:70e287df5439
|
| o  changeset:   575:7ae70ddd2b6e
| |  branch:      mongo
| |
| o  changeset:   574:904da90475ef
| |  branch:      mongo
| |
| o  changeset:   567:cad7a006965b
|/   branch:      mongo
|
o  changeset:   566:70e287df5439
|  user:        me
|
```

Looks like someone has created a new branch in the repo, which is fine: I just want to push my changes to the default branch, but I don't know how.

How can I push changeset 576? Do I need to specify that it's to branch default?

Comment: Are you sure you just want to push a new head and don't want to merge with (from or into) this branch?

Comment: I definitely don't want to push to the mongo branch: I'd like to keep it separate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mercurial's *push* command has the `-r` option to limit the push to changes up to a given revision:

> *If -r/--rev is used, the specified revision and all its ancestors will be
>   pushed to the remote repository.*

This implicates that you also limit the branch you're going to push. To push all changes up to the tip of the default branch, you could run:

```
$ hg push -r default
```

This will ignore your *mongo* branch. Instead of branch names, you can also use specific revisions:

```
$ hg push -r 576
```

Obviously, as long as revision 576 is the tip of the default branch, both commands have the same effect.

On a side note, there is an often handy shortcut to push only the parent revision of the currently checked out working copy, using a period as the revision specifier:

```
$ hg push -r .
```

Comment: This is solid advice, but for this case it seems like it's way overthinking it. He likely just needed to first pull the default branch in order to do a merge/rebase which would avoid creating a remote head.

Answer (score 5):

Something else is going on because a remote branch like `mongo` doesn't cause a multiple head abort, only multiple heads on the same branch do. [Update: Actually, you *do* get a remote branch abort, analogous to a remote head abort, unless you have `Push new branch` checked in the Synchronize menu of your TortoiseHg as I did.]

No matter the cause, the proper procedure is to commit to your local repo (which you've done), then *pull* the remote changes, *merge* them with yours, *commit* the result and, finally, *push* the merged changes to the repo.

There is an extension called `fetch` which helps consolidate this process into a single step.  You can learn more about it [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html).

Don't just force the push to the remote repo!  This is just avoiding responsibility for the merge and may even break things, such as a build system which relies on having all changes in an unbranched line.  At the least you will confuse or irritate those you are working with.  Unless that is your intention, in which case, full steam ahead. :)

You really need to read some of the basics about collaboration before you start doing it.  Start [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html).

Answer (score 4):

See a very recent discussion on this

- [Branching in Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317857/branching-in-mercurial)

Mercurial will always complain about creating new heads on the remote. You must use either --force or --new-branch when creating a new head.

[Edit:]

This is specifically to make the user aware that he is introducing multiple head in remote repository.  Normal practice is not to create heads by using push command. If you want to create multiple heads on the remote repo (Which usually is central repo).

As Binary Phile, says perfectly, this causes pushing the merge upwards. Which is not good.

Comment: I'm concerned about using force. Should I use "-new-branch default" or something like that?

Comment: @AP257: Yes. It is better to use "-new-branch .." See my edit.

Comment: @AP257: You should also look at Oben Sonne answer which contains one important consideration. Some times we want to push our changes for the default head to remote repository and continue to have multiple heads locally. In such a case, his answer also applies.