# When should I use push with force?

Tags: mercurial

I recently started studying Mercurial. The thing I don't understand is the message I get then I try to push to the remote central repository after someone already did another push (without pulling the data). What I get is the message that I try to push a new head and, as an advice, the possible solution "Use push with force".

Now, I read Joel tutorial about Mercurial and it's said there that it's a terrible advice - one should not push a new head with force, making multiple heads. I understand that intuitively.

What I don't understand is - when would it actually be appropriate to use push with force? Are there any specific situations when this is preferrable to merging operation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a --new-branch flag needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948574/why-is-a-new-branch-flag-needed)

Comment: I disagree. They say there about a new branch. But it's not explained there about new heads

Comment: "The mercurial philosophy is that you should not be pushing things which make it harder for other users of the repository. Relevant to this question is that multiple heads make it harder for other developers, since they would then need to merge your changes."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could see a usage to defer merging where:

- dev-A has pushed a change,
- dev-B has made an incompatible change and pushed without merging,
- integrator-C or maintainer-C :) will be the person deciding and merging.

In this case, dev-B could push with --force, thus providing the server with all the necessary information. Of course something similar could be achieved with branches or bookmarks if it were known in advance that the incompatibility would arise, but.. sometimes we don't. Mercurial now has the possibility to push bookmarks, so it would probably be a better option..

Answer (score 2):

Push with force can be useful for automated builds/testing: developers push changes they want to test to a specific server. Each push then triggers builds and tests. Multiple heads aren't an issue in this case.
One example of this is [the 'try' server Mozilla uses](https://wiki.mozilla.org/ReleaseEngineering/TryServer#How_to_push_to_try).

Of course, lots of variations on this are possible.